# How to create a query for multiple ranges?

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm experiencing issues with how to create a multi range query.

So I'm using a library that creates a query using a `setQuery` function, which accepts an object. [Scroll down to setQuery](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/native/advanced/reactivecomponent.html)

Now currently my function creates a single range query and works fine. I followed the [ES Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) so it matches what I have currently written, which is...

```js
    const queryObject = {
      query: {
        range: {
          [searchType]: {
            gte: from,
            lte: to,
            boost: 2.0,
          },
        },
      },
      value: queryItem,
    };
```

But I can't seem to find any documentation for multiple ranges that has a similar shape. 
Any recommendations on how to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it!
So let's say I have an array of ranges

```js
const sampleRanges = [{from: 1990, to: 1992}, {from: 1993, to: 1995}, {from: 1996, to: 2002}]
```

I created a function to map over those values soo...

```js
const generateRangeQuery = () => {
      return sampleRanges.map(value => ({
        range: {
          [searchType]: {
            gte: value.from,
            lte: value.to,
            boost: 2.0,
          },
        },
      }));
    };
```

And the query for multi ranges should then look like:

```
const query = {
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: generateRangeQuery(),
      minimum_should_match: 1,
      boost: 1.0,
    },
  },
};
```

and this works for me!

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer, so your question won't appear as "Not solved" :)

Comment: thx! it wouldn't let me answer it until a few hours/days later and i forgot to follow up :)